# What is the easiest way to show to view the MPS log?

Tags: mps

The MPS log can be found in $HOME/.MPS*/system/log/idea.log.

Do I really need to remember this or is there an easier way to find the log?

This question is meant to increase searchability of practical MPS issues.

Answer (score 1):

In the menu, go to Help --> Show Log in Explorer. This will bring you directly to the location of the idea.log file.

Answer (score 0):

**Help --> Show Log in Explorer**

But as MPS gives you freedom to write plugins, you can write one to have a customized log viewer for your application.